# Writing on a file, info ends up in the console instead

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, methods

This is a project, where I need to make a list of items that the user will input and they need to be written in a file. However it prints `@4761920nan` for each entry in it. And then it prints it all that's supposed to be in the file on the console instead. Any light on this issue will be appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    ofstream data("list.txt");
    int n;
    cout << "How many cabins are in your region? "; cin >> n; cout<<endl;
       cabin*tour=
     new cabin[n];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        tour[i].nameInput();
        data<<tour[i].nameOutput();
        tour[i].capacity();
        data<<tour[i].capacityOutput();
        tour[i].gps();
        data<<tour[i].gpsOutput();
    };

    data.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This is what `nameOutput()` looks like:

```
char cabin::nameOutput()
{
    cout<<"Name: "<< name<<endl;
}
```

Comment: We don't have a view on `tour[i].nameOutput()`. What is output depends on this.

Comment: Oh..sorry. It's a simple `cout<<` command that prints the text. Now that i think of it, maybe it shoudn't be cout but the name of the file instead? I tried this but it reads it as a variable, not as a file

Comment: `data<<tour[i].nameOutput();` here, `tour[i].nameOutput()` should return a string, int, *something* that can be written into a stream. It would immensely help if you can attach a minimal example of what `.nameOutput()` (and the other output functions) do.

Comment: No, that's correct to use `data`, but what you put in the stream is not correct, but we don't know what it is.

Comment: `char cabin::nameOutput()
{
    cout<<"Name: "<< name<<endl;
}`

Comment: It has `char` as return type but nothing is returned. That will return UB and `data << ` will write random gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `cabin::nameOutput` has `char` as the return type but **doesn't return anything**. Thus, the call

```
data << tour[i].nameOutput();
```

will write appropriately to standard output (due to cout), but not appropriately to `data`. Since **nothing is returned**, the output written to `data` is undefined behaviour.

In order to fix this, you may want to specify a return type in your functions like so

```
// the return type depends on the type of `name`
// this may be char*, std::string, or something else appropriate
std::string cabin::nameOutput()
{
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    return name;
}
```